# Is it possibel to enable X86 PMU in QEMU emulation mode (without KVM)?

Tags: linux, qemu, kvm, performance

I am trying to run `perf` in my Linux system, but WSL2 and virtual-box 6.1 do NOT detect the *hardware* PMU in system.

So, I installed `qemu-system-x86_64` in Linux VM, and tried to run QEMU in emulation mode to use the emulated PMU.

But I still got the kernel log saying 'no PMU counter' when running QEMU in emulation mode.

I tried to run `qemu-system-x86_64` with `-cpu IvyBridge` or `-cpu BroadWell`, no one worked.

I ran `qemu -cpu help` and got following supported CPU models.

```
VirtualBox:/mnt$ qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu help
Available CPUs:
x86 486                   (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 486-v1                                                                
x86 Broadwell             (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Broadwell-IBRS        (alias of Broadwell-v3)                         
x86 Broadwell-noTSX       (alias of Broadwell-v2)                         
x86 Broadwell-noTSX-IBRS  (alias of Broadwell-v4)                         
x86 Broadwell-v1          Intel Core Processor (Broadwell)                
x86 Broadwell-v2          Intel Core Processor (Broadwell, no TSX)        
x86 Broadwell-v3          Intel Core Processor (Broadwell, IBRS)          
x86 Broadwell-v4          Intel Core Processor (Broadwell, no TSX, IBRS)  
x86 Cascadelake-Server    (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Cascadelake-Server-noTSX  (alias of Cascadelake-Server-v3)                
x86 Cascadelake-Server-v1  Intel Xeon Processor (Cascadelake)              
x86 Cascadelake-Server-v2  Intel Xeon Processor (Cascadelake)              
x86 Cascadelake-Server-v3  Intel Xeon Processor (Cascadelake)              
x86 Conroe                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Conroe-v1             Intel Celeron_4x0 (Conroe/Merom Class Core 2)   
x86 Cooperlake            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Cooperlake-v1         Intel Xeon Processor (Cooperlake)               
x86 Denverton             (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Denverton-v1          Intel Atom Processor (Denverton)                
x86 Dhyana                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Dhyana-v1             Hygon Dhyana Processor                          
x86 EPYC                  (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 EPYC-IBPB             (alias of EPYC-v2)                              
x86 EPYC-Milan            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 EPYC-Milan-v1         AMD EPYC-Milan Processor                        
x86 EPYC-Rome             (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 EPYC-Rome-v1          AMD EPYC-Rome Processor                         
x86 EPYC-Rome-v2          AMD EPYC-Rome Processor                         
x86 EPYC-v1               AMD EPYC Processor                              
x86 EPYC-v2               AMD EPYC Processor (with IBPB)                  
x86 EPYC-v3               AMD EPYC Processor                              
x86 Haswell               (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Haswell-IBRS          (alias of Haswell-v3)                           
x86 Haswell-noTSX         (alias of Haswell-v2)                           
x86 Haswell-noTSX-IBRS    (alias of Haswell-v4)                           
x86 Haswell-v1            Intel Core Processor (Haswell)                  
x86 Haswell-v2            Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX)          
x86 Haswell-v3            Intel Core Processor (Haswell, IBRS)            
x86 Haswell-v4            Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX, IBRS)    
x86 Icelake-Client        (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Icelake-Client-noTSX  (alias of Icelake-Client-v2)                    
x86 Icelake-Client-v1     Intel Core Processor (Icelake)                  
x86 Icelake-Client-v2     Intel Core Processor (Icelake)                  
x86 Icelake-Server        (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Icelake-Server-noTSX  (alias of Icelake-Server-v2)                    
x86 Icelake-Server-v1     Intel Xeon Processor (Icelake)                  
x86 Icelake-Server-v2     Intel Xeon Processor (Icelake)                  
x86 IvyBridge             (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 IvyBridge-IBRS        (alias of IvyBridge-v2)                         
x86 IvyBridge-v1          Intel Xeon E3-12xx v2 (Ivy Bridge)              
x86 IvyBridge-v2          Intel Xeon E3-12xx v2 (Ivy Bridge, IBRS)        
x86 KnightsMill           (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 KnightsMill-v1        Intel Xeon Phi Processor (Knights Mill)         
x86 Nehalem               (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Nehalem-IBRS          (alias of Nehalem-v2)                           
x86 Nehalem-v1            Intel Core i7 9xx (Nehalem Class Core i7)       
x86 Nehalem-v2            Intel Core i7 9xx (Nehalem Core i7, IBRS update)
x86 Opteron_G1            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Opteron_G1-v1         AMD Opteron 240 (Gen 1 Class Opteron)           
x86 Opteron_G2            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Opteron_G2-v1         AMD Opteron 22xx (Gen 2 Class Opteron)          
x86 Opteron_G3            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Opteron_G3-v1         AMD Opteron 23xx (Gen 3 Class Opteron)          
x86 Opteron_G4            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Opteron_G4-v1         AMD Opteron 62xx class CPU                      
x86 Opteron_G5            (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Opteron_G5-v1         AMD Opteron 63xx class CPU                      
x86 Penryn                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Penryn-v1             Intel Core 2 Duo P9xxx (Penryn Class Core 2)    
x86 SandyBridge           (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 SandyBridge-IBRS      (alias of SandyBridge-v2)                       
x86 SandyBridge-v1        Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)                
x86 SandyBridge-v2        Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update)   
x86 Skylake-Client        (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Skylake-Client-IBRS   (alias of Skylake-Client-v2)                    
x86 Skylake-Client-noTSX-IBRS  (alias of Skylake-Client-v3)                    
x86 Skylake-Client-v1     Intel Core Processor (Skylake)                  
x86 Skylake-Client-v2     Intel Core Processor (Skylake, IBRS)            
x86 Skylake-Client-v3     Intel Core Processor (Skylake, IBRS)            
x86 Skylake-Server        (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Skylake-Server-IBRS   (alias of Skylake-Server-v2)                    
x86 Skylake-Server-noTSX-IBRS  (alias of Skylake-Server-v3)                    
x86 Skylake-Server-v1     Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake)                  
x86 Skylake-Server-v2     Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake, IBRS)            
x86 Skylake-Server-v3     Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake, IBRS)            
x86 Snowridge             (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Snowridge-v1          Intel Atom Processor (SnowRidge)                
x86 Snowridge-v2          Intel Atom Processor (Snowridge, no MPX)        
x86 Westmere              (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 Westmere-IBRS         (alias of Westmere-v2)                          
x86 Westmere-v1           Westmere E56xx/L56xx/X56xx (Nehalem-C)          
x86 Westmere-v2           Westmere E56xx/L56xx/X56xx (IBRS update)        
x86 athlon                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 athlon-v1             QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+                   
x86 core2duo              (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 core2duo-v1           Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz 
x86 coreduo               (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 coreduo-v1            Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2600  @ 2.16GHz 
x86 kvm32                 (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 kvm32-v1              Common 32-bit KVM processor                     
x86 kvm64                 (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 kvm64-v1              Common KVM processor                            
x86 n270                  (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 n270-v1               Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz          
x86 pentium               (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 pentium-v1                                                            
x86 pentium2              (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 pentium2-v1                                                           
x86 pentium3              (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 pentium3-v1                                                           
x86 phenom                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 phenom-v1             AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor         
x86 qemu32                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 qemu32-v1             QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+                   
x86 qemu64                (alias configured by machine type)              
x86 qemu64-v1             QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+                   
x86 base                  base CPU model type with no features enabled    
x86 host                  KVM processor with all supported host features  
x86 max                   Enables all features supported by the accelerator in the current host

Recognized CPUID flags:
  3dnow 3dnowext 3dnowprefetch abm ace2 ace2-en acpi adx aes amd-no-ssb
  amd-ssbd amd-stibp apic arat arch-capabilities avic avx avx2
  avx512-4fmaps avx512-4vnniw avx512-bf16 avx512-vpopcntdq avx512bitalg
  avx512bw avx512cd avx512dq avx512er avx512f avx512ifma avx512pf
  avx512vbmi avx512vbmi2 avx512vl avx512vnni bmi1 bmi2 cid cldemote clflush
  clflushopt clwb clzero cmov cmp-legacy core-capability cr8legacy cx16 cx8
  dca de decodeassists ds ds-cpl dtes64 erms est extapic f16c flushbyasid
  fma fma4 fpu fsgsbase fsrm fxsr fxsr-opt gfni hle ht hypervisor ia64 ibpb
  ibrs ibrs-all ibs intel-pt invpcid invtsc kvm-asyncpf kvm-hint-dedicated
  kvm-mmu kvm-nopiodelay kvm-poll-control kvm-pv-eoi kvm-pv-ipi
  kvm-pv-sched-yield kvm-pv-tlb-flush kvm-pv-unhalt kvm-steal-time kvmclock
  kvmclock kvmclock-stable-bit la57 lahf-lm lbrv lm lwp mca mce md-clear
  mds-no misalignsse mmx mmxext monitor movbe movdir64b movdiri mpx msr
  mtrr nodeid-msr npt nrip-save nx osvw pae pat pause-filter pbe pcid
  pclmulqdq pcommit pdcm pdpe1gb perfctr-core perfctr-nb pfthreshold pge
  phe phe-en pku pmm pmm-en pn pni popcnt pschange-mc-no pse pse36 rdctl-no
  rdpid rdrand rdseed rdtscp rsba rtm sep sha-ni skinit skip-l1dfl-vmentry
  smap smep smx spec-ctrl split-lock-detect ss ssb-no ssbd sse sse2 sse4.1
  sse4.2 sse4a ssse3 stibp svm svm-lock svme-addr-chk syscall taa-no tbm
  tce tm tm2 topoext tsc tsc-adjust tsc-deadline tsc-scale tsx-ctrl umip
  v-vmsave-vmload vaes vgif virt-ssbd vmcb-clean vme vmx vmx-activity-hlt
  vmx-activity-shutdown vmx-activity-wait-sipi vmx-apicv-register
  vmx-apicv-vid vmx-apicv-x2apic vmx-apicv-xapic vmx-cr3-load-noexit
  vmx-cr3-store-noexit vmx-cr8-load-exit vmx-cr8-store-exit vmx-desc-exit
  vmx-encls-exit vmx-entry-ia32e-mode vmx-entry-load-bndcfgs
  vmx-entry-load-efer vmx-entry-load-pat vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl
  vmx-entry-load-rtit-ctl vmx-entry-noload-debugctl vmx-ept vmx-ept-1gb
  vmx-ept-2mb vmx-ept-advanced-exitinfo vmx-ept-execonly vmx-eptad
  vmx-eptp-switching vmx-exit-ack-intr vmx-exit-clear-bndcfgs
  vmx-exit-clear-rtit-ctl vmx-exit-load-efer vmx-exit-load-pat
  vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl vmx-exit-nosave-debugctl
  vmx-exit-save-efer vmx-exit-save-pat vmx-exit-save-preemption-timer
  vmx-flexpriority vmx-hlt-exit vmx-ins-outs vmx-intr-exit vmx-invept
  vmx-invept-all-context vmx-invept-single-context
  vmx-invept-single-context vmx-invept-single-context-noglobals
  vmx-invlpg-exit vmx-invpcid-exit vmx-invvpid vmx-invvpid-all-context
  vmx-invvpid-single-addr vmx-io-bitmap vmx-io-exit vmx-monitor-exit
  vmx-movdr-exit vmx-msr-bitmap vmx-mtf vmx-mwait-exit vmx-nmi-exit
  vmx-page-walk-4 vmx-page-walk-5 vmx-pause-exit vmx-ple vmx-pml
  vmx-posted-intr vmx-preemption-timer vmx-rdpmc-exit vmx-rdrand-exit
  vmx-rdseed-exit vmx-rdtsc-exit vmx-rdtscp-exit vmx-secondary-ctls
  vmx-shadow-vmcs vmx-store-lma vmx-true-ctls vmx-tsc-offset
  vmx-unrestricted-guest vmx-vintr-pending vmx-vmfunc
  vmx-vmwrite-vmexit-fields vmx-vnmi vmx-vnmi-pending vmx-vpid
  vmx-wbinvd-exit vmx-xsaves vmx-zero-len-inject vpclmulqdq waitpkg
  wbnoinvd wdt x2apic xcrypt xcrypt-en xgetbv1 xop xsave xsavec xsaveerptr
  xsaveopt xsaves xstore xstore-en xtpr

VirtualBox:/mnt$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.28)
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

So, is it possible to enable PMU counters in emulation mode of QEMU (without using KVM)?

Comment: Pretty sure the problem here is that the hyperV virtualization that your WSL runs in doesn't allow access to these registers to the Linux guest, and not that the qemu running in the Linux guest would lack support.

Comment: So, can the QEMU not emulate the PMU hardware of X86 without real hardware support?

Comment: How is software supposed to emulate a zero-overhead performance counter?!

Comment: If QEMU can emulate instructions, it should emulate the registers. Maybe I can try running qemu-system-aarch64 in X86 VM to fully emulate an ARM64 platform to get PMU feature of ARM?

Comment: Again, how do you envision software emulating this kind of hardware counter? You do realize what that counter does!

Comment: I am not sure if it is OK to ask WSL2 question in this website, if so, I will post another question on enabling PMU in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PMU can be emulated without a kernel driver(something just like KVM) or a real PMU hardware. In KVM, the PMU is virtualized in kernel space through `perf_event_create_kernel_counter`, that is the kernel's perf framework which deals with PMU hardware. So the key of WSL perf problem is, does hyperV support PMU virtualization? I don't have certain answer for this question, but I think the answer is probably
*NO*.

Comment: In virtualization environment, the PMU in VM depends on the hypervisor. VMware product supports guest PMU, but as you said, it may not be support in hyperV, I checked the google, but did NOT find solid answers on this in hyperV. In emulation mode, I assume PMU could be emulated by emulator, if the emulator emulates instructions, it is possible to capture the number of instructions executed. But again, it depends on emulator implemenation..

Comment: @戴胜东 please don't post in non-English languages here. Anyway, answers should be posted as answers, not as comments. But answers also need to be in English as this is the language of the site. I have deleted the comments, but please feel free to include the comments in your answer in English.